# Fix protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm new to using Ecto and Elixir and I've come across an error that I can't explain. My code looks just like the example in the Ecto README.

Here are my modules for the Ecto Model and Query

```
defmodule Registration do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "registrations" do
    field :user_id, :string
    field :created_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
    field :updated_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
  end
end

defmodule RegistrationQuery do
  import Ecto.Query

  def by_user(user_id) do
    query = from r in Registration,
          where: r.user_id == ^user_id,
         select: r
    Repo.all(query)
  end
end
```

Here is how I call the query function

```
registrations = Repo.all RegistrationQuery.by_user("underwater")
```

This all seems exactly in line with the Ecto documentation, and I can't find anything saying otherwise. But I get the following error.

```
protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [%Ensalutilo.Registration{user_id: "underwater"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `by_user/1` function is already calling `Repo.all`, so when you call `registrations = Repo.all(...)` later on, you are passing the result of the first `Repo.all` as argument, which is a list  as you see in the error message!

To be clear, you get this error message because you can pass anything that implements the Ecto.Queryable protocol into Repo.all.