# Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [....]

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the same error as [Fix protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671867/fix-protocol-ecto-queryable-not-implemented-error) but with what I think are different circumstances

I want to (following the Phoenix book) limit the `Estimate`s that can be deleted to those owned by a user, except if they have Admin rights.

```
  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}, user) do
    user_estimates =
        case user.customer_id == 1 do
            true ->
                IO.inspect("Admin")
                Repo.all(Estimate)
            false ->
                IO.inspect("Non-Admin")
                assoc(user, :estimates)
        end
    estimate = Repo.get!(user_estimates, id)
    Repo.delete!(estimate)
```

But when I use this function as an Admin I get

> ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for  [list of all Estimates]

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
Repo.all(Estimate)
```

`Repo.all` actually executes the query passed and returns the results as a list. If you want an `Ecto.Queryable` that contains all estimates, just return `Estimate`.

This should work:

```
user_estimates =
  case user.customer_id == 1 do
    true ->
      IO.inspect("Admin")
      Estimate
    false ->
      IO.inspect("Non-Admin")
      assoc(user, :estimates)
  end
```